# Nginx Routing path to server

Tags: nginx

I have a few sites. Each site has its own "server" section with a server_name that looks like this

```
server {
   ...
   server_name siteA.example.com;
   root /var/www/siteA;
   ...
}
```

I can therefore bring up the site using the url http://siteA.example.com

I however also need to bring up the site by using the url http://example.com/siteA
How can this be done?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Two options to add to your config below ...

**Option 1:**

```
server {
    ...
    server_name example.com;
    ...
    location /siteA {
        root /var/www/siteA;
        ...
    }
    location /siteB {
        root /var/www/siteB;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
server {
    ...
    server_name example.com;
    ...
    location /siteA {
        return       301 http://siteA.example.com$request_uri;
    }
    location /siteB {
        return       301 http://siteB.example.com$request_uri;
    }
    ...
}
```

First option simply serves from `example.com/siteA` in addition while second option redirects to `siteA.example.com`

Comment: Excellent Dayo. Just one more clarification. Each server's configuration is kept in separate files inside a sites-available dir. eg: sites-available/siteA.conf, sites-available/siteB.conf. In your option 2 above, each 301 results in a lookup for siteX.example.com. What would be the best way to avoid this lookup by using localhost for instance. Something like 301 http://siteB.localhost$request_url and then in siteB.conf having server_name siteB.localhost, siteB.example.com.

Comment: Clarification. What would be the best way to redirect to the configuration file for siteX depending on the location used? Eg. location /siteB ends up using siteB.conf.

Comment: The redirection is trivial and follows good practice. If you really want to avoid this, then go with Option 1. Personally, I'll use Option 2 as while it can be good to allow multiple routes to a resource (usually for historical reasons), each resource should be served via one route alone. Hence, `/var/www/siteA/somefile.ext` can be reached from `example.com/SiteA/somefile.ext` and from `siteA.example.com/somefile.ext` but it should really only always be served from one of the two and users requesting via other routes should be redirected accordingly.

Comment: Good strategy. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this finally worked. Not sure why root is not working though, any explanation?