# How do I run multiple symfony apps on the same domain in subfolders

Tags: symfony, nginx

I'd like to run multiple symfony apps on the same Nginx server and same domain in subfolders.

e.g. I got *`app1`* and *`app2`* as symfony apps, my domain is *`host.name`*
I'd like to run:

- host.name/app1/
- host.name/app2/

With apache, it wasn't very tricky using *`Alias`* directive but I don't get that easy with Nginx.

Here is the official documentation supplied by sensiolabs and considering you're using one app for one main domain:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#nginx

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think this answer is for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108044/nginx-routing-path-to-server