# How to server setup with nginx in ubuntu?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx

My domain is like example.com and nginx file like below.
So my root path is /var/www/campaignmanager/bannerad/public.

So my domain open in browser like example.com but i want to open it like **example.com/campaignmanager** or **www.example.com/campaignmanager**

Please help me.

```
server { 
    listen 80; 
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/campaignmanager/bannerad/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name exmaple.com www.example.com;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @upstream;
    }

    location @upstream {
     location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri /index.php =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to only change your `server_name exmaple.com www.example.com;` to `server_name exmaple.com www.example.com/campaignmanager;` and then `sudo systemctl reload nginx` Hope this helps you! Let me know.

Comment: Is this helps you??

Comment: This is not working Hiren.

Comment: when i restart nginx. get error like. Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: Update your location path to `/sample`

Comment: Hiren it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a combination of server and location directives.

```
 server { 
        listen 80; 
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/campaignmanager/bannerad/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name exmaple.com/sample

        location /sample {
          try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @upstream;
        }

        location @upstream {
         location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri /index.php =404;
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include fastcgi_params;
         }
       }
    }
```

Please excuse for syntax mistakes.
https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-location-directive/
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: when i restart nginx get error like. Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: @sanjaymokariya my bad, the answer was not proper. Updated. Also checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108044/nginx-routing-path-to-server