# Nginx setting with Applications in docker

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config

I deployed 3 applications in my docker as below. heimdall , portainer and Wiznote.

[image: docker]

And nginx is in my ubuntu server. I want use a domain ABC.COM to access my applications in docker with ABC.COM/heimdall, ABC.COM/portainer , ABC.COM/Wiznote.

How do I set my nginx setting?

Comment: I have no experience with nginx but you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19111103/13664939) answer.